# Notepad++ regex for text surrounded by double newline

Tags: notepad++, boost-regex

I am trying to find all text blocks in a file, that contain a string, matching the following regex: `D[:\/\\]+Apps[\/\\]+`
and are surrounded by **double newlines**.

For example in this text:

```
00,36,00,31,00,39,00,33,00,34,00,65,00,30,00,38,00,39,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v2.0.50727\NGenService\Roots\D:/Apps/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/Architecture Tools/GraphProviderPackage/Microsoft.VisualStudio.GraphProviderPackage.dll]
"Status"=dword:00000003

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v2.0.50727\NGenService\Roots\D:/Programs/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/Architecture Tools/GraphProviderPackage/Microsoft.VisualStudio.GraphProviderPackage.dll\0]
"Scenario"=dword:00000020

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v2....
```

What I want to be found is:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v2.0.50727\NGenService\Roots\D:/Apps/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/Architecture Tools/GraphProviderPackage/Microsoft.VisualStudio.GraphProviderPackage.dll]
"Status"=dword:00000003
```

Having in mind, that `"Status"=dword:00000003` is on a different line

So far this is the closest I got:

```
\r?\n\r?\n(([\s\S](?!\r?\n\r?\n))*)D[:\/\\]*Apps[\/\\]*(([\s\S](?!\r?\n\r?\n))*).\r?\n\r?\n
```

but Notepad++ says that my regex is invalid, even though in regex101 it matches it the way I want it.

Comment: First, you should probably have something like **D[:\/]*** - because after **D** you have 2 characters, not one. I change d the order of the slashes only because the SE script does some voodoo :) No need to change in original. It is probably the same with **(\s\S)***

Comment: Also, please save the Regex101 search and provide us the link, so we can understand your situation better.

Comment: Are these single or multiple lines? Do they always start with the same string?

Comment: The text could be comprised of multiple lines and should be matched if it doesn't contain consecutive newline characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>
- Find what: `\R\R\K\[.+?D:/Apps/.+?(?=\R\R)`
- **TICK** *Match case*
- **TICK** *Wrap around*
- **SELECT** *Regular expression*
- **TICK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
\R\R            # 2 any kind of linebreak
\K              # forget them
\[              # openning square bracket
.+?             # 1 or more any character, not greedy
D:/Apps/        # literally
.+?             # 1 or more any character, not greedy
(?=\R\R)        # poritive lookahead, make sure we have 2 linebreak after
```

**Screenshot:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but the string "Status"=dword:00000003 is on a new line and it should still be matched. Using this method - it wouldn't.

Comment: I also edited my question, to clarify what should be matched, please check it out again.

Comment: @Veselin_01: Sorry but I don't see any problem! It works, doesn't it?

Comment: Well it matches a string with the 2 paragraphs together, when it should only select the one with "D:\Apps" in it.

Comment: @Veselin_01: As you can see in screenshot, it works fine. If you have another test case than the one you've given please dit your question and add this test case.

Comment: It is edited now, please check it out.

Comment: I have provided some more information, could you check it out?

Comment: @Veselin_01: I don't see any modifications in your question since March 17. My solution works fine with your actual example.

Comment: There is a modification. One paragraph is added which breaks your solution as you can see in the following screenshot: https://imgur.com/a/bsGxa8D

Comment: @Veselin_01:Just change `+` into `.+?` (not greedy). See my edit.